# FastCGI c++ store requests?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fastcgi

I need to make any applciation using fastcgi and c++. A thread different from the one that has the FCGX_Accept_r(...) loop is the one doing the processing, so I was hoping I could store the requests as they come in a queue and have the second thread send the response on the output stream in each requests.
This is what I got so far.

```
void Listen(){
    FCGX_Request request;
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);
    while(FCGX_Accept_r(&request)>= 0)
    {
        AddRequest(request); //just adds it to a std::queue<FCGX_Request> queue
        request = *NewRequest();
    }
}

FCGX_Request* NewRequest()
{
    FCGX_Request* request;
    request = new FCGX_Request();
    FCGX_InitRequest(request, 0, 0);
    return request;
}
```

The second thread is just checking if something is on the queue (they both share it). If there's a request, it'll do whatever and it's supposed to print the response and call FCGX_Finish_r(&request). When I get to printing the output, the app doesn't crash, but nginx puts the error "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream" in the error file. I'm not really sure what's going on. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the output stream in FCGX_Request is a pointer.

If I uncomment out the line

```
request = *NewRequest();
```

it's able to print the response, but if I can't reinitialize the request to a new one each time, then I can't store them in the queue.

What can I do to proberly store these FCGX_Requests in the queue for another thread to process? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
void Listen(){
    FCGX_Request *request = NewRequest();
    while(FCGX_Accept_r(request)>= 0)
    {
        // Make your queue hold pointers
        AddRequest(request); //just adds it to a std::queue<FCGX_Request*> queue
        request = NewRequest();
    }
}

FCGX_Request* NewRequest()
{
    FCGX_Request* request = new FCGX_Request();
    FCGX_InitRequest(request, 0, 0);
    return request;
}
```

Don't forget to delete the requests when you are done with them.

Comment: I don't need to do request = new FCGX_Request after each add? Won't it all be the same reference?

Comment: Yes, I must have been sleeping. Fixed the answer.